# Is this a LivePatch bug in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-core, configure

I've just tried the command line approach again. Here are the results:

arno@arno-PC:~$ sudo pro detach [sudo] password for arno: Are you sure? (y/N) Y This machine is now detached. arno@arno-PC:~$ sudo ua attach C141aD6nC4HAhnUkQLkFcZuxm7Cx7x Enabling default service esm-infra Updating package lists Ubuntu Pro: ESM Infra enabled Enabling default service livepatch Stderr: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

Stdout: Unable to configure Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch config remote-server=https://livepatch.canonical.com' [exit(1)]. Message: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

ERROR: Unable to configure Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch config remote-server=https://livepatch.canonical.com' [exit(1)]. Message: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

Unable to determine current instance-id This machine is now attached to 'Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription'

SERVICE ENTITLED STATUS DESCRIPTION esm-infra yes enabled Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure livepatch yes disabled Canonical Livepatch service

NOTICES Operation in progress: pro attach

Enable services with: pro enable

Account: [SECRET]

Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription arno@arno-PC:~$ pro enable livepatch This command must be run as root (try using sudo). arno@arno-PC:~$ sudo pro enable livepatch One moment, checking your subscription first Stderr: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

Stdout: Unable to configure Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch config remote-server=https://livepatch.canonical.com' [exit(1)]. Message: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

ERROR: Unable to configure Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch config remote-server=https://livepatch.canonical.com' [exit(1)]. Message: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

arno@arno-PC:~$

I did a fresh install on my laptop and I get the same results. The message "snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected" also comes up on my laptop. Why does it not connect ? How do I set about fixing the problem ?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output from the terminal again and format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the [edit window](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1439902/edit).

Comment: Are you completely sure that you are using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and not a different release like 22.10? It matters.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.    I just made a screen-print of "Settings About".  HARDWARE MODEL  Gigabyte Technology Co.   MEMORY  16.0 GiB.   PROCESSOR  Intel Core i7-3770 @ 3.4GHz x 8.   OS NAME  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.   OS TYPE  64-bit.   GNOME VERSION 42.4.